# Can Azure APIM give fine grained control of access to individual FHIR API calls

Tags: fhir-server-for-azure

I'm using Open Source FHIR Server on Azure.  I have an Azure API Manager and all access to the FHIR server has to go through this.  I want some users only to do GETs but others to do GET, PUT, POST etc.  I expected to apply a Product to each call within the API but it seems this level of fine grained control is not possible, Product applies across the whole API.  What am I missing?